# How does Dynamic Data Masking work in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

What was the internal mechanism used in the dynamic data masking in SQL Server?

I tried to find the function which has been called during the masking select query execution.

Turned-on SQL Server Profiler to track the background queries being executed in during the masking select statement execution.

I couldn't find the function being used for masking like `default()`, `email()`, `partial()` and `custom()`.

Nothing specific, I have used the code available in MSDN site.

I have following questions regarding the masking mechanism.

1. Are the masking functions (default, partial, email, custom) called for each and every row of the data?
2. Is SQL Server creating any predefined masking column to return the masking data for each row?

For example: I have created a masking for an email column. Is SQL Server creating the predefined column for Email making column in addition to original one.

Comment: Any idea about the internal mechanism about would be appreciated.